# Update using positional operator ($) in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a document containing an array of objects. I wanted to update a particular element in the array. Tried using MongoDB shell, it works fine. But when I use in Mongoose in NodeJs, it is not working. The command is same in both the cases.

NodeJs code

```js
 const updateAttendance = await classModel.updateOne(
            {
                _id: item.classId,
                'studentAttendance.studentId': item.studentId,
            },
            { $set: { 'studentAtendance.$.present': true } }
        )
```

Schema defination

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const moment = require('moment')
const student = mongoose.Schema({
    studentId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        unique: true,
    },
    present: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
})
const classes = mongoose.Schema({
    date: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
        validate: {
            validator: (value) => {
                return moment(value, 'DD/MM/YYYY', true).isValid()
            },
            message: 'Provide a valid date in the format of DD/MM/YYYY',
        },
    },
    courseId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Course',
    },
    studentAttendance: [
        {
            type: student,
        },
    ],
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Class', classes)
```

Sample data

```js
 {
        "date": "20/06/2021",
        "_id": "60cf5446970dc063e40356d3",
        "courseId": "60ce2c3aca275c868089ac48",
        "studentAttendance": [
            {
                "present": false,
                "_id": "60cf5446970dc063e40356d4",
                "studentId": "60ce315f9f83a24544414705"
            },
            {
                "present": false,
                "_id": "60cf5446970dc063e40356d5",
                "studentId": "60ce31ba9f83a2454441470a"
            },
            {
                "present": false,
                "_id": "60cf5446970dc063e40356d6",
                "studentId": "60ce38e49f83a24544414712"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
  }
```

What am I doing wrong or where is the problem?

Comment: There is a typo in the update part: 'studentAtendance'.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the schema def, just taking a punt in the dark that you dont explicitly say its an ObjectId.

Easy solve, just wrap "item.studentId" in mongoose.Types.ObjectId().

So your new code would be like

```
const updateAttendance = await classModel.updateOne({
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(item.classId),
      'studentAttendance.studentId': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(item.studentId),
            },
            { $set: { 'studentAtendance.$.present': true } }
        )
```

Don't forget `const mongoose = require('mongoose');`

Based on the update your update statement  needs 'updating'.  try fixing the spelling of `studentAttendance` vs `studentAtendance` in the `$set` statement.

Comment: I did but still the same issue. I have updated the schema defination as an update to the question.